# Force sidewaysfigure to be in a specific position

Tags: rotating

I'm trying to force a sideways figure to be drawn in a specific point of the text, but I haven't found any valid solution. In particular, I need to achieve the following layout:

- page 1 - contains only text
- page 2 - contains the sideways figure
- page 3 - text and figures

Here the code I'm using.

```
\begin{sidewaysfigure}[counterclockwise]
  \centering
    \scalebox{0.99}
    {\includegraphics[width=0.99\textwidth]{myfigure}}
    \caption{def}
    \label{def}
\end{sidewaysfigure}
```

When I compile, `myfigure` figure is rendered only after page 3, but it's not I want to achieve.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no need to use `\scalebox` and scaling within `\includegraphics` (also your example as posted is missing a closing `}`.

It is hard to tell given the description without a complete example document but perhaps you just want to put `\clearpage` before and after the figure on page 2.

Comment: It worked. Thank you for your reply. Also +1 for pointing out the missing bracket. I'm using tex for mac os. When I compile the figure is not rendered with the correct orientation (`counterclockwise`). Any suggestions? My goal is to present it from left to right (the caption would be set on the right). Now, it is rendered for left to right (the caption is on the left side).

Comment: just looked at the package, counterclockwise is an option to the package not to the figure. `\usepackage[counterclockwise]{rotating}`

Comment: Thank you. I set \usepackage[figuresright]{rotating} and it works.